# How to find differing lines in file regardless of order

Tags: unix, diff

Is there a way to use the unix diff tool to find differing lines regardless of order? For example:

file A:

```
A
B
C
```

file B:

```
D
C
A
```

Would return something like

```
Only in file B
D
Only in file A
B
```

I am not interested in line number, just finding the lines that are unique in each file.

Comment: The Unix `comm` tool does this (in conjunction with `sort -u`). Can you use it? (A lot of questions here are homework assignments and students are often limited in what they're allowed to use.)

Comment: Nope, this isn't a homework assignment. Comm does what I need. If you want the rep you can answer the question.